# Wielding a one handed large weapon with two hands

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

I looked for an answer to this but all I was able to find was questions about wielding two handed weapons in one hand.

I remember a rule somewhere that stated if a character used a large one handed weapon with two hands it counted as a two handed medium weapon without penalties.(Example: Wielding a large Longsword with two hands would make it count as a two handed weapon)

Is this a House-rule that I confused as an actual rule or is this actually a rule somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is actually an official rule. Though there is also a -2 penalty for using a weapon not meant for your size.

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons

Also Page 144 of the Core Rulebook

> **Weapon Size**
>
> Every weapon has a size category. This designation indicates the size
>   of the creature for which the weapon was designed.
>
> A weapon's size category isn't the same as its size as an object.
>   Instead, a weapon's size category is keyed to the size of the intended
>   wielder. In general, a light weapon is an object two size categories
>   smaller than the wielder, a one-handed weapon is an object one size
>   category smaller than the wielder, and a two-handed weapon is an
>   object of the same size category as the wielder.
>
> Inappropriately Sized Weapons: A creature can't make optimum use of a
>   weapon that isn't properly sized for it. A cumulative –2 penalty
>   applies on attack rolls for each size category of difference between
>   the size of its intended wielder and the size of its actual wielder.
>   If the creature isn't proficient with the weapon, a –4 nonproficiency
>   penalty also applies.
>
> The measure of how much effort it takes to use a weapon (whether the
>   weapon is designated as a light, one-handed, or two-handed weapon for
>   a particular wielder) is altered by one step for each size category of
>   difference between the wielder's size and the size of the creature for
>   which the weapon was designed. For example, a Small creature would
>   wield a Medium one-handed weapon as a two-handed weapon. If a weapon's
>   designation would be changed to something other than light,
>   one-handed, or two-handed by this alteration, the creature can't wield
>   the weapon at all.

Some DM's may handwave the -2 penalty for certain things. There really isn't that much of a difference between a shortspear meant for a medium character and a spear meant for a small character. An large creature's one-handed club is not that different from a medium creature's greatclub. That would be the place that a houserule would most likely come into play.

Comment: Note the second paragraph in the quoted text appears to be a sidebar on how large of an object a weapon is. The entire rest of the quote is about the size category of the weapon (ie the intended size of its wielder)!